# Spring Tool Suite - Port 8080 required by Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.0 is already in use

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I get the following error when running codes in Spring Tool Suite.

..............................................................................

Port 8080 required by Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.0 is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

..............................................................................

Below is a screenshot of the error. [image: Error-Spring Tool Suite]

Also, below is what I get on localhost:8080

[image: localhost:8080]

By changing port numbers in server.xml (i.e. `<Connector acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" executor="tomcatThreadPool" maxKeepAliveRequests="15" port="${bio.https.port}" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" redirectPort="${bio.https.port}"/>`
), I get the same error with different port numbers.

Comment: So have you checked what you have running on port 8080? Why not use another port other than 8080?

Comment: @Aeseir, thanks for your comment. Please review the question again with more info.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a application running on 8080, so you need to terminate whatever is running currently on 8080 port.

If you running Windows use:

```
netstat -a -o | find "8080"
```

If you running Mac OS (which i think you are) use:

```
sudo lsof -i :8080
```

Terminate that application and then launch Pivotal.

Otherwise you can change pivotal server port in the config file:

```
<your tc server folder location>/conf/catalina.properties
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I sudo lsof -i :8080, it shows that TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN) is listening. I stopped the Pivotal tc Server. Once I run the src in one of the project, the Pivotal tc Server starts again. If I select src and click run again, the Port 8080 error appears, so I see no output of running the Java codes. I'm a complete Java newbie, is there something else you would recommend?

Comment: So you saying first time you run it there are no problems, but second time you run the source code it throws the error?

Answer (score 4):

steps to be followed

- change the port number in catalina.properties file under server folder

  e.g.
   
  bio.http.port=18080
  bio.https.port=18844
- kill the java.exe running on port 8080(or any other port which poses the issue)- 
  Use [TcpView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) to kill the process on specfic port
- Right click on the server and then click on "clean tc server work directory"
- Right click on the server and then click on "Clean"
- and there u go "baaaam"

  [image: Cleaning server folder]

Answer (score 4):

I want to update "user4023394's" answer for windows :

- double click on "Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition.."

[image]

- a window will appear like the below image, change port number for "neo.http.port" and "neo.https.port" [circled in the image]

[image]

- right click on "Pivotal tc Server .." and click on "clean tc server work directory .."

[image]

- restart the server.

Answer (score 3):

You can enter:

```
run configurations
```

Find you app name in tree struct below:

```
java application
```

and in:

```
(X) = Arguments
```

tab  ---> VM arguments
add something like this:

```
 -Dserver.port=8888
```

8888 can be any port you want run http server on it.

That's all, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

First of all check your port : 8080 on your system.

I am using linux , i have followed this approach and it worked for me.

**Step 1 :** sudo netstat -nlp | grep 8080

It has shown which PID is listening to my port.

*tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1112/java*

**Step 2 :** sudo kill -TERM 1112

And run your project on STS :

Run As -> Run on Server

And it worked fine on http://localhost:8080/myapp/

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it happened when you shutdown wrongfully sts software. Ex : close software while running your project or didn't stay full working status are saving.

1. Clean tc server work directory
2. Restart your machine
3. Clean tc server work directory

In my machine its worked

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse under windows and you get this sort of problems - try killing javaw.
[<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>] -> Processes; kill javaw.

This is a quick fix without much thinking so use with caution.

Answer (score 0):

Reference:- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port

Add the server.port=8081 in application.properties file

This worked for me. For more details, you can click on the above link.

Next time when you try to run, stop the server and then run.

Answer (score 0):

Port 8088 required by Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.2 is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

Answer (score -1):

just click on Pivotal Tc Server Developer Edition v3.1 it will open overview then go to ports there you get option port name- HTTP/1.1 ,portnumber-8080, there change port number- 8888 don't make any changes in Catalina.XML.