# I found this error while starting a service in eclipse sts. Its also displays me a pom.xml file error

Tags: java, eclipse, server

Port 8080 required by Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v4.0 is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).

Comment: just stop the other service which is running on 8080 already.

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174981/spring-tool-suite-port-8080-required-by-pivotal-tc-server-developer-edition-v3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Tool Suite - Port 8080 required by Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.0 is already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174981/spring-tool-suite-port-8080-required-by-pivotal-tc-server-developer-edition-v3)